Firebase Cloud Messaging Error 'Error: Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required' even when topic is set and subscribed to
I'm trying to migrate to the cloud messaging HTTP V1 API and when I try to send a message from a Firebase cloud function I'm getting an error that says

"Error: Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required"

even though I have a topic.
Prior to the migration everything was working correctly in the old format. Devices subscribed to topics, and messages were sent to topics.
At this point I've straight up copied the documentations example and have subscribed to such a topic on both my Android and iPhone and I'm still getting the error saying there must be at least one topic, token or condition in my cloud function logs.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1
{
  "message": {
    "topic": "news",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Breaking News",
      "body": "New news story available."
    },
    "data": {
      "story_id": "story_12345"
    },
    "android": {
      "notification": {
        "click_action": "TOP_STORY_ACTIVITY"
      }
    },
    "apns": {
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "category" : "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

And then in my cloud function trying to send a message
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
});

The document update triggers and then the error happens
exports.myUpdate = onDocumentUpdated("{mypaths}", (event) => {

  
 let message = {
        "message": {
            "topic": "news",
            "notification": {
                "title": "Breaking News",
                "body": "New news story available."
            },
            "data": {
                "story_id": "story_12345"
            },
            "android": {
                "notification": {
                    "click_action": "TOP_STORY_ACTIVITY"
                }
            },
            "apns": {
                "payload": {
                    "aps": {
                        "category" : "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    admin.messaging().send(message).then((response) => {
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });
}

The full error
Error: Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required
    at validateMessage (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-internal.js:53:15)
    at Messaging.send (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:185:50)
    at /workspace/index.js:235:20
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/onInit.js:33:16
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:338:14)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/trace.js:18:37
    at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/firestore.js:247:78)
    at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:113:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


The problem was an extra "message": { } around the payload
This stops triggering the error.
   let message = {
        "topic": "news",
        "notification": {
            "title": "Breaking News",
            "body": "New news story available."
        },
        "data": {
            "story_id": "story_12345"
        },
        "android": {
            "notification": {
                "click_action": "TOP_STORY_ACTIVITY"
            }
        },
        "apns": {
            "payload": {
                "aps": {
                    "category" : "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
                }
            }
        }
    }

